# How can I access hte data from the method GET through another controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have two controllers: OcorrenciasAPIController and IgnicoesAPIController. In my OcorrenciasAPIController I need to access the data from the method GET of my IgnicoesAPIController.
Here is what I'm doing to doing in my OcorrenciasAPIController, to get the data from the method GET:

```
             IgnicoesAPIController controller = null;
            controller.GetIgnicoes();
```

I'm not sure if this is the right approach. Am I doing it right or does this have some problems? If so, is there another way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a demo to show using a method from another controller:

Startup.cs:

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddTransient<AController,AController>();
            ...
        }
```

A Controller:

```
public class AController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        public string ReturnResult() {
            return "success";
        }
    }
```

B Controller:

```
public class BController : Controller
    {
        private AController aController;
        public BController(AController a) {
            aController = a;
        }
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var s = aController.ReturnResult();
            return Ok(s);
        }
    }
```

result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have a common method in your controllers then you need to have a common class for both of controllers,In the first place you need to have a common base controller

```
public class BaseController:ApiController
{
    public void CommonMethod()
    {
       
    }
}
```

then inherit from than by your controllers

```
public class ApiControllerA : BaseController
{
    public void MethodA()
    {
        base.CommonMethod();
    }
}
```

And also in second controller

```
public class ApiControllerB : BaseController
{
    public void MethodB()
    {
        base.CommonMethod();
    }
}
```

Now Put what is in your get method in  common method to be accessible in both of  of controllers

Comment: but I don«t have a common method, I just need what's in the method get

Comment: Put what is in your get method in a common method to be accessible in both of controllers